# Почему у меня вылетает ошибка java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, android, файлы

У меня есть код, с помощью которого скачиваются песни. Вот он:

```
try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlStr).openStream());
                     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                    byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                        fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // handle exception
                }

                Mp3File mp3file = null;
                try {
                    mp3file = new Mp3File(file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedTagException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvalidDataException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
                    mp3file.removeId3v1Tag();
                }
                if (mp3file.hasId3v2Tag()) {
                    mp3file.removeId3v2Tag();
                }
                if (mp3file.hasCustomTag()) {
                    mp3file.removeCustomTag();
                }
                ID3v2 id3v2Tag;
                if (mp3file.hasId3v2Tag()) {
                    id3v2Tag = mp3file.getId3v2Tag();
                } else {
                    // mp3 does not have an ID3v2 tag, let's create one..
                    id3v2Tag = new ID3v24Tag();
                    mp3file.setId3v2Tag(id3v2Tag);
                }
                id3v2Tag.setTrack("5");
                id3v2Tag.setArtist(performer);
                id3v2Tag.setTitle(title);
                id3v2Tag.setAlbum("Lalala");
                id3v2Tag.setYear("2001");
                id3v2Tag.setGenre(12);
                id3v2Tag.setArtistUrl(songImg.getText().toString());
                try {
                    id3v2Tag.setAlbumImage(recoverImageFromUrl(songImg.getText().toString()),"");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Так вот, на версии андорид 9 всё хорошо работает, а вот при тестировании на 6-ке вылетает такой Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-2
Process: music.player.musicplayer.audio.media.fm.video.radio.video.songs.equalizer.apps.free.android.lalala.download.search, PID: 31039
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/nio/file/Paths;
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.FileWrapper.<init>(FileWrapper.java:21)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:57)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:45)
    at musicplayer.audioplayer.equalizer.mp3player.widget.TopAdapter$TopViewHolder$4.run(TopAdapter.java:292)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.nio.file.Paths" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/music.player.musicplayer.audio.media.fm.video.radio.video.songs.equalizer.apps.free.android.lalala.download.search-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/music.player.musicplayer.audio.media.fm.video.radio.video.songs.equalizer.apps.free.android.lalala.download.search-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.FileWrapper.<init>(FileWrapper.java:21) 
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:57) 
    at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:45) 
    at musicplayer.audioplayer.equalizer.mp3player.widget.TopAdapter$TopViewHolder$4.run(TopAdapter.java:292) 
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) 
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: Попробуйте переключиться на Java 1.8, прописав в Gradle модуля app:

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

Comment: @Виталий Перятин, Не помогло. А есть чё-нить подобное для модуля Project?

Comment: приведенный вами фрагмент код не причем. ошибка из консоли говороит Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.nio.file.Paths" , т.е. не найден класс класс Paths .  java.nio.file.Paths появился в Java 7, если вы будете понижать версию апи андроида,  то рано или поздно получите множество таких проблем. либо ищите место в коде, где вы используете этот класс и меняйте на что-то более старое, либо не понижайте апиху.

Comment: @Дмитрий, А как повысить и что именно? В Project или в App?

Comment: я давно не писал ничего под андроид, но насколько я помню, там выбирается минимальная версия совместимого апи. чем ниже версия, тем выше совместимость с устройствами, но тем меньше новшеств языка вам доступно. если вам недоступен это класс, значит вы пытаетесь использовать программу на устройстве, которое использует более ранюю версию апи